# Why does my dice sum distribution in R output incorrecet sum's once we get to 15+dice (using stars and bars counting logic)

Tags: r, sum, dice

If you are familiar with counting problems in mathematics, you may be familiar with stars and bars counting logic.

An example of this would be "You have 5 cookies, in how many ways can you give your 2 friends these 5 cookies?". You can set this up as an equation x_1+x_2=5, where x_i is the amount of cookies you give to friend i. This answer would then be solved using stars and bars as:

You have 5 stars (cookies) and there is 1 bar (plus sign) order these 6 things by choosing where the 5 cookies go --> 6 choose 5.

This same logic can be applied to summing dice, with a couple of extra steps. If you were to roll 4 dice, and were wondering in how many ways can you roll a 14. You can set up an equation as: `x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=14, where 1<= x_i <= 6.`
In order to get rid of lower limits, you could define a new variable y_i s.t. y_i = x_i-1. Our new equation becomes:

```
y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=10, where 0<= y_i <=5.
```

You do this, because in order for stars and bars counting to work, you need your lower limit to be 0. Now, in order to deal with our upper limits, we use inclusion-exclusion.
We first count all possibilities if there were no upper limits (i.e. 0<= y_i)

```
|S|= # of  possibilities with no bounds = (10-3) choose (10)
|A_i|= # of possibilities where y_i >=6 = (10-3-6) choose (10-6)
[A_i n A_j| = # of possibilities where y_i,y_j >= 6 = (10-3-12) choose (10-12)
Similarly you do all 3 and 4 intersections.
```

Then solving,

```
Answer = |S| - (4 choose 1)*|A_i|+(4 choose 2)*|A_i n A_j|-(4 choose 3)*|three intersecetions| + (4 choose 4)*|4 intersections| = 146
```

Then, to generalize this process:

```
x_1+x_2+...+x_k = n (where k is the number of dice and n is the sum value)
#possibilities = summation from i=0 to k [(-1)^i]*[k choose i]*[(n-1-6*i) choose (n-k-6*i)]
```

I programmed this process in R, and it works up to 14 dice. However, once we use 15+ dice, my process begins to be fault. I was hoping someone could look through my work and code to determine where I went wrong, or if this is a problem in the R code itself. Thank you.

r Code:

```
dice_sum_distribution_sb <- function(dice = 2,sides = 6){
  ## default values for dice and sides are 2 and 6 respectively
  
  ## count of all possibilities
  all <- sides^dice
  
  ## define min and max and all sum possibilities
  minSum <- dice
  maxSum <- dice*sides
  sumRange <- c(minSum:maxSum)
  
  ## initialize list for sumCounts
  sumCounts <- c(rep(0,length(sumRange)))
  
  ## for loop function to count possibilities of every sum
  for(i in 1:length(sumRange)){
    ## which sum we will work with
    value <- sumRange[i]
    
    ## initialize stars and bars for sum
    #stars <- value - dice ## fixes lower limits
    #bars <- dice-1 ## x_1+x_2+...+x_n has (n-1) +'s --> (n-1) bars
    
    ## initialize count for incl-excl
    count <- 0
    for(j in 0:dice){
      n <- value-1-6*j
      k <- value-dice-6*j
      
      ## counting using choose function
      if(n>-1){
        ##print(paste(value,",",j,": ",count," + ",(-1)^j," * ",choose(dice,j)," * ",choose(n,k)))
        count<- count+((-1)^j)*choose(dice,j)*choose(n,k)
      }
      
      
      ## counting using factorial function
      # if(k>=0){
      #   v1 <- ((-1)^j)*(factorial(n)/(factorial(n-k)*factorial(k))*(factorial(dice)/(factorial(dice-j)*factorial(j)))



      #   if(!is.na(v1)){
      #     count <- count+v1
      #   }
      # }
      
      
    }## end of j for loop
    
    sumCounts[i]<-count
    
  }## end of i for loop
  
  distribution <- data.frame(sum=sumRange,
                             sumCount=sumCounts,
                             pdf=sumCounts/all)
  
  
  return(distribution)
  
}
```

I have some lines commented out as that is the other things I tried.

Answer (score 0):

If `dice==15`, at one point you are calculating `choose(89, 75)`.  That is too big to be computed exactly, so you get rounding error.

If you want to get exact results with such large numbers, you need to use `gmp` or some other package that allows arbitrary precision.

For example, this does intermediate calculations in the `"bigz"` format, then switches back to standard numerics at the end.  At some number of dice you won't be able to switch back, because even the final values will be too big.

```r
library(gmp)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gmp'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     %*%, apply, crossprod, matrix, tcrossprod
dice_sum_distribution_sb <- function(dice = 2,sides = 6){
  ## default values for dice and sides are 2 and 6 respectively
  
  ## count of all possibilities
  all <- sides^dice
  
  ## define min and max and all sum possibilities
  minSum <- dice
  maxSum <- dice*sides
  sumRange <- c(minSum:maxSum)
  
  ## initialize list for sumCounts
  sumCounts <- as.bigz(c(rep(0,length(sumRange))))
  
  ## for loop function to count possibilities of every sum
  for(i in 1:length(sumRange)){
    ## which sum we will work with
    value <- sumRange[i]
    
    ## initialize count for incl-excl
    count <- 0
    for(j in 0:dice){
      n <- value-1-6*j
      k <- value-dice-6*j
      
      ## counting using choose function
      if(n>-1){
        count<- count+((-1)^j)*chooseZ(dice,j)*chooseZ(n,k)
      }
      
    }## end of j for loop
    
    sumCounts[i]<-count
    
  }## end of i for loop
  
  distribution <- data.frame(sum=as.numeric(sumRange),
                             sumCount=as.numeric(sumCounts),
                             pdf=as.numeric(sumCounts/all))
  
  
  return(distribution)
  
} 

dice_sum_distribution_sb(15)
#>    sum    sumCount          pdf
#> 1   15           1 2.126822e-12
#> 2   16          15 3.190234e-11
#> 3   17         120 2.552187e-10
#> 4   18         680 1.446239e-09
#> 5   19        3060 6.508077e-09
#> 6   20       11628 2.473069e-08
#> 7   21       38745 8.240374e-08
#> 8   22      116055 2.468284e-07
#> 9   23      317970 6.762657e-07
#> 10  24      806990 1.716324e-06
#> 11  25     1915356 4.073622e-06
#> 12  26     4282980 9.109138e-06
#> 13  27     9076405 1.930390e-05
#> 14  28    18315675 3.895419e-05
#> 15  29    35332650 7.514627e-05
#> 16  30    65372310 1.390353e-04
#> 17  31   116325135 2.474029e-04
#> 18  32   199542465 4.243914e-04
#> 19  33   330639445 7.032114e-04
#> 20  34   530137275 1.127508e-03
#> 21  35   823747890 1.751966e-03
#> 22  36  1242073550 2.641670e-03
#> 23  37  1819496655 3.869746e-03
#> 24  38  2592085185 5.512905e-03
#> 25  39  3594444165 7.644745e-03
#> 26  40  4855600971 1.032700e-02
#> 27  41  6394206690 1.359934e-02
#> 28  42  8213538270 1.746874e-02
#> 29  43 10296957375 2.189980e-02
#> 30  44 12604578705 2.680770e-02
#> 31  45 15071885925 3.205523e-02
#> 32  46 17610885675 3.745523e-02
#> 33  47 20114111295 4.277914e-02
#> 34  48 22461407505 4.777143e-02
#> 35  49 24529001175 5.216883e-02
#> 36  50 26199964377 5.572267e-02
#> 37  51 27374880105 5.822151e-02
#> 38  52 27981391815 5.951145e-02
#> 39  53 27981391815 5.951145e-02
#> 40  54 27374880105 5.822151e-02
#> 41  55 26199964377 5.572267e-02
#> 42  56 24529001175 5.216883e-02
#> 43  57 22461407505 4.777143e-02
#> 44  58 20114111295 4.277914e-02
#> 45  59 17610885675 3.745523e-02
#> 46  60 15071885925 3.205523e-02
#> 47  61 12604578705 2.680770e-02
#> 48  62 10296957375 2.189980e-02
#> 49  63  8213538270 1.746874e-02
#> 50  64  6394206690 1.359934e-02
#> 51  65  4855600971 1.032700e-02
#> 52  66  3594444165 7.644745e-03
#> 53  67  2592085185 5.512905e-03
#> 54  68  1819496655 3.869746e-03
#> 55  69  1242073550 2.641670e-03
#> 56  70   823747890 1.751966e-03
#> 57  71   530137275 1.127508e-03
#> 58  72   330639445 7.032114e-04
#> 59  73   199542465 4.243914e-04
#> 60  74   116325135 2.474029e-04
#> 61  75    65372310 1.390353e-04
#> 62  76    35332650 7.514627e-05
#> 63  77    18315675 3.895419e-05
#> 64  78     9076405 1.930390e-05
#> 65  79     4282980 9.109138e-06
#> 66  80     1915356 4.073622e-06
#> 67  81      806990 1.716324e-06
#> 68  82      317970 6.762657e-07
#> 69  83      116055 2.468284e-07
#> 70  84       38745 8.240374e-08
#> 71  85       11628 2.473069e-08
#> 72  86        3060 6.508077e-09
#> 73  87         680 1.446239e-09
#> 74  88         120 2.552187e-10
#> 75  89          15 3.190234e-11
#> 76  90           1 2.126822e-12
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>